# Trouble with filter in Microsoft Graph query using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, microsoft-graph-api

I'm having trouble converting the following Microsoft Graph rest query to C#. The following works in the graph explorer:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteid}/lists/{listid}/items?$expand=fields&$filter=fields/Recruit_x0020_Status eq 'Initial Discussion'
```

So far I have the following which doesn't work:

```
    var options = new List<QueryOption>()
    {
        new QueryOption("expand", "fields"),
        new QueryOption("filter", "startswith(Recruit_x0020_Status', 'Initial')")
    };

    var list = await _client
        .Sites[siteId]
        .Lists[listId]
        .Items
        .Request(options)
        .Header("Prefer", "HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly")
        .GetAsync();
```

The error returned is very generic and not helpful:

```
ServiceException: Code: generalException
Message: General exception while processing
```

I tried adding the filter directly into the chained fluent query via `.Filter("startswith(Recruit_x0020_Status,'Initial')")`, but I receive an error about a bad filter clause.

What am I missing here? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using `fields/Recruit_x0020_Status eq 'Initial Discussion'` in QueryOptios as    `new QueryOption("filter", "fields/Recruit_x0020_Status eq 'Initial Discussion'")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `QueryOption` is missing `fields` property name in `startswith` and there is also a typo in `Recruit_x0020_Status'`. The char `'`.

```
new QueryOption("filter", "startswith(Recruit_x0020_Status', 'Initial')")
```

It should be

```
new QueryOption("filter", "startswith(fields/Recruit_x0020_Status, 'Initial')")
```

Generally the url will looks like this

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteid}/lists/{listid}/items?$expand=fields&filter=startswith(fields/Recruit_x0020_Status,'Initial')
```

Comment: So the solution was to pass in the `fields/` prefix to the filter. I suppose the filter passed into the `QueryOption` object has to match the url parameter query exactly.